# Android LBS Services - Emulator doesn't show map

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have made a project which displays the current address of the values of latitude and longitude passed on by emulator control.
I have also constructed a **MapView** which shows the points on the map as well.

But the problem being that MapView doesn't work even after generating the **MD5 fingerprint key** nad registering it with google.

I am using **emulator - Google API7**.

Someone suggest something so that the map shows the co-ordinates on the emulator.

Comment: What does it do? What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it won't load the map.

Your gmaps key is generated using your Live API key and when you run the emulator it either uses your debug.keystore or the default eclipse/intellij debug.keystore.

You could generate another google maps api key using your debug.keystore and use this then swap it out at production time.

or test it now with your live keystore, then have faith it'll work when you create your live APK :-)

Comment: I used my debug.keystore to generate gmaps key from the url https://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html.
I then used that key im my AndroidManifest.xml.

I guess this is what u wanted to suggest, but even this won't work.

Comment: As I said, eclipse will be using it's own debug key. It's found in /YourHomeDir/.android